# Extracting a Module from Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am having a little problem in my workplace where we have a IIS 6 server where Orchard (1.7) will not run. We are planning an upgrade but that's going to take some time.

Since we are using this site on IIS6 only to run one particular custom module we wrote for Orchard (basically a MVC module with its own Controllers/Actions etc.) I was thinking that a temporary solution could be to rip that module out of Orchard and run it independently.

Of course this extraction needs to take into account how many ties I have with the framework. I was wondering if there is some kind of guide to perform this and if there is something I need to take specially into account.

I am using the Users in Orchard so I would probably have to rewrite some users code. I am also using the Authorizer, which again may mean I need to re-wire something else.

It seems like a daunting job so I am looking for some quick tips on how to proceed if you know any.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what components you actually use within your module.
Hard to write any tutorial on this, really.

Regarding `Orchard.Users` - you could drop all related code usages and rely on the default ASP.NET roles-based authentication/authorization model.

If dependency injection is what you want to keep, then you need to [integrate it yourself](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html) (for Autofac, but other DI containers will also work). Feel free to copy and change any Orchard components that you use, stripping the unneeded code.

In my opinion the hardest thing to strip out and replace would be any code that relies on content items - hope you don't have it. Rewriting this pieces sounds like an overkill. But if you just use `IRepository`, going for plain NHibernate or EF instead should be quite easy.